# What is rank list in tucker decomposition?

Tags: python, tensor, decomposition, tensorly

I am going to decompose a 4D tensor using tucker decomposition in python. I found a library, **tensorly**, to do this.
I only want to perform the decomposition on the **first** and **second** dimensions. To perform tucker decomposition on some modes (not all modes) using **tensorly** I have to use **partial_tucker** command. This is my code:

```
F = 256
D = 96
h = 5
w = 6
ranks = [89, 48] 
modes = [0, 1]

tensor = tl.tensor((np.arange(F*D*h*w).reshape((F, D, h, w))).astype(np.float64))
core, factors = partial_tucker(tensor, modes=modes, rank=ranks)
```

This code works well, but when I am trying to change the rank list, for example:

```
ranks = [3,4]
```

I get an error as follows:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\PhD_Thessaloniki\Codes\LRF_Convolutional\tucker-decomposition.py", line 49, in <module>
    core, factors = partial_tucker(tensor, modes=modes, rank=ranks)
  File "C:\Users\Milad\Anaconda3\envs\tensorly\lib\site-packages\tensorly\decomposition\_tucker.py", line 109, in partial_tucker
    eigenvecs, _, _ = svd_fun(unfold(core_approximation, mode), n_eigenvecs=rank[index], random_state=random_state)
  File "C:\Users\Milad\Anaconda3\envs\tensorly\lib\site-packages\tensorly\backend\core.py", line 913, in partial_svd
    S, V = scipy.sparse.linalg.eigsh(
  File "C:\Users\Milad\Anaconda3\envs\tensorly\lib\site-packages\scipy\sparse\linalg\_eigen\arpack\arpack.py", line 1689, in eigsh
    params.iterate()
  File "C:\Users\Milad\Anaconda3\envs\tensorly\lib\site-packages\scipy\sparse\linalg\_eigen\arpack\arpack.py", line 571, in iterate
    raise ArpackError(self.info, infodict=self.iterate_infodict)
scipy.sparse.linalg._eigen.arpack.arpack.ArpackError: ARPACK error 3: No shifts could be applied during a cycle of the Implicitly restarted Arnoldi iteration. One possibility is to increase the size of NCV relative to NEV.
```

I don't know if there is a constraint to define the rank in tucker decomposition or not, but when I am trying to perform decomposition on only one dimension, for example:

```
ranks = [3]
modes = [0]
```

or

```
ranks = [4]
modes = [1]
```

works well again.

I want to know:

Is this an algorithmic or code (tensorly) problem (constraint)?

What is this problem?

What rank lists are valid?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Tucker relies on higher-order PCA. The error you are seeing is is in the sparse SVD, applied to an unfolding of the main tensor.

You can try a different SVD function (`svd` parameter in partial_tucker), you can see the available option using `tensorly.tenalg.svd.SVD_FUNS`.

You also might want to try a tensor with random elements, using `tensorly.random.random_tensor` or `tensorly.randn`.